# How to get a property value of an object which is located randomly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
res = {
  A: { device001: 1, device002: 2 },
  B: { device003: 3, device004: 4 }
};
```

For the above object in Javascript, I need to get the value of device001, however, device001 is exist but the position of device001 is unknown, for example:

```
res = {
  A: { device004: 4, device002: 2 },
  B: { device003: 3, device001: 1 }
};
```

please tell me how to get that value, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could grab the values of your object using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and then use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the first value object which has `"device001"` as a key which you can check using the [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method. You can then use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to obtain the result from the object if it is found:

```js
const obj = {
  A: { device001: 1, device002: 2 },
  B: { device003: 3, device004: 4 }
};

const search = "device001";
const result = Object.values(obj).find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(search))?.[search];
console.log(result);
```

If you can't support optional chaining yet, then you can check the truthiness of the result of using `.find()` first before trying to obtain the value from it:

```js
const obj = {
  A: { device001: 1, device002: 2 },
  B: { device003: 3, device004: 4 }
};

const search = "device001";
const found = Object.values(obj).find(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty(search));
const result = found && found[search];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `values` of `res` using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and then, check if it has a property of the key you're looking for using [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```js
const res = {
  "A": { "device001": 1, "device002": 2 },
  "B": { "device003": 3, "device004": 4 }
};

const getValueInObject = (obj = {}, itemKey) => {
  for(const item of Object.values(obj))
    if(item.hasOwnProperty(itemKey))
      return item[itemKey];
  return;
}

console.log( getValueInObject(res, "device001") );
console.log( getValueInObject(res, "device004") );
console.log( getValueInObject(res, "") );
```

Answer (score 0):

I support Nick answer. But for more clarity on the object type. I am giving you the explanation.

Object in JavaScript is like Dictionary with Key/Value pairs.

For the simple extracting of the property value, you can try the below code.

```
var res = {
    A: { device001: 1, device002: 2 },
    B: { device003: 3, device004: 4 }
  };
  
 
  console.log(res["A"]["device001"]); // output 1
  console.log(res["B"]["device001"]); // output undefined
```

undefined since the "device001" does not exist on B.

Comment: yes, this is the problem which I met, i hope to get the only value is 1, instead of 1 undefined, is there any solution?